# Different between two characters in Swift (quote vs smart/curl quote)

Tags: ios, swift, string

I need to filter the array of the Dictionary based on the search string. In Dictionary, I have a key "name", I need to compare the entered string in textfield to the name key in Dictionary.

```
func textChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text == "" {
        self.filteredArrayStoreList = self.arrayStoreList
    } else {
        self.filteredArrayStoreList.removeAll()
        print("Text: \(textField.text ?? "")")
        let filteredArray = self.arrayStoreList.filter { ($0.name?.contains((textField.text ?? "")))!}
        self.filteredArrayStoreList = filteredArray
        self.noLocationFoundView.isHidden = true //filteredArrayStoreList.count == 0
    }
    self.searchLocationTabelView.reloadData()
}
```

In Dictionary, the name key value is " Vimal's ".
But in textfield, I will get the text as " Vimal‘s ". How to search for the single quotes.

Comment: Just a question, You want to consider "Vimal's" and " Vimal‘ " both are same?

Comment: @Rajan No, I got the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**'** (ascii-39) is the normal quote, and **‘** (ascii-8216) is called "smart" or "curly" quote. this quote is the appear on iOS device keyboard.User can on/off this feature from settings

> Settings -> General -> Keyboard-> Smart punctuation

That is the reason for not matching these 2 strings.You can do 2 things to solve your problem. Because we don't know app user's device on/off that feature

1. simply you can enter dictionary names without special characters
2. you can find and replace that smart/curl quote with normal quote before check

this is the example

```
let name:String = "vimal‘s" 
print(name.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "'"))
//result "vimal's"
```